# How to use CSS and JS npm modules globally in Electron Project?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ecmascript-6, electron, materialize

I have an Electron project I'm working on, but I'm facing an inconvenience when attempting to use *jQuery* and *Materialize-css* globally. Is there a way to include/import/require them (they are already installed via `npm install --save` and are present in `node_modules` directory), so the will be valid in every new child window the application opens? Currently I'm using the **HTML** way (`<link rel...` for the css styles and `<script src...` for the JavaScript files) but as my project has lots of child windows, which load different html files, I would like to use those modules globally.

Answer (score 0):

I use:

```
npm install "framework" -g
```

Comment: This installs a module globally in a multiple projects use aspect, as far as I know. My question is not how to install a module, but how to use it across my whole single project, how to always include the module?

Comment: For me if the module is in the package.json it is available in all .js files, isn't it?

Comment: but I have to `require()` it in every single js file and this is what I want to avoid. Is it possible?

Comment: I see your point Emil, I do use require( ) in every page. But your question is good, I'll do some search about it.